# $geowithin with Foriegn Collection on $lookup

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have two collections Members and MobileUserLocations - where each users locations is saved(Can be multiple) as userId as the foreign field.

**Members:**

```
{
  _id: ObjectId("591553ffa4233a181506880c"),
  userName: "Test user"
}
```

**MobileUserLocations:**

```
{ _id: ObjectId("59156070a4233a1815068b6b"),
  userId: ObjectId("591553ffa4233a181506880c"),
  location: {type: "Point", coordinates: [76.9121, 10.2232]]},
  updatedOn: 2017-05-12T07:12:48.626Z,
  status: 1 
},
{ _id: ObjectId("59156070a4233a1815068b6b"),
  userId: ObjectId("591553ffa4233a181506880c"),
  location: {type: "Point", coordinates: [76.8121, 10.1232]]},
  updatedOn: 2017-05-12T07:12:48.626Z,
  status: 1 
}
```

I want to get the Members who are within a radius - say 5km with reference to a particular geo point - say: [10.0132295, 76.3630502] (lat,lng format).

I tried this:

```
collection.aggregate([
                                {$match: {_id: { $ne: options.accessToken.userId }},
                                { "$lookup": {
                                    "localField": "_id",
                                    "from": "MobileUserLocations",
                                    "foreignField": "userId",
                                    "as": "userLocInfo"
                                  }
                                },
                                {
                                    $project: {
                                        _id: 1,
                                        userLocInfo: {
                                           "$filter": {
                                                "input": "$userLocInfo",
                                                "as": "userLoc",
                                                "cond": { 
                                                            "$eq": [ "$$userLoc.status", -1],  
                                                       "$$userLoc.location": {"$geoWithin": {"$centerSphere": [[76.3630502, 10.0132295], 5 / 3963.2]}}
                                                        }
                                            } 
                                        }
                                    }
                                },
                                {$unwind: "$userLocInfo"}

                      ]
```

But not getting. If I am removing the $geowithin from the filter cond, it is getting, otherwise not getting. But if I am individullay querying the collections, I am getting the result.

Can anyone know the issue?

Answer (score 3):

That does not work because [`$geoWithin`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/geoWithin/) is not a "logical operator", but it's a "query operator" and can only be used in an aggregation pipeline using [`$match`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/). Fortunately for you, that is really what you want. Though you don't yet see why:

```
collection.aggregate([
  { "$match": { 
    "_id": { "$ne": options.accessToken.userId }
  }},
  { "$lookup": {
    "localField": "_id",
    "from": "MobileUserLocations",
    "foreignField": "userId",
    "as": "userLocInfo"
  }},
  { "$unwind": "$userLocInfo" },
  { "$match": {
    "userLocInfo.status": -1, 
    "userLocInfo.updatedOn": "2017-05-12T12:11:04.183Z", 
    "userLocInfo.location": {
      "$geoWithin": {
        "$centerSphere": [[76.3630502, 10.0132295], 5 / 3963.2]
      }
    }
  }}
])
```

There's a really good reason for that aside from it's the only way it works. To understand, look at the `"explain"` output:

```
    {
        "$lookup" : {
            "from" : "MobileUserLocations",
            "as" : "userLocInfo",
            "localField" : "_id",
            "foreignField" : "userId",
            "unwinding" : {
                "preserveNullAndEmptyArrays" : false
            },
            "matching" : {
                "$and" : [ 
                    {
                        "status" : {
                            "$eq" : -1.0
                        }
                    }, 
                    {
                        "updatedOn" : {
                            "$eq" : "2017-05-12T12:11:04.183Z"
                        }
                    }, 
                    {
                        "location" : {
                            "$geoWithin" : {
                                "$centerSphere" : [ 
                                    [ 
                                        76.3630502, 
                                        10.0132295
                                    ], 
                                    0.00126160678239806
                                ]
                            }
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    }
```

What that shows you is that both the [`$unwind`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) and following [`$match`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/) get absorbed into the [`$lookup`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/) stage itself. This means that the [`$geoWithin`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/geoWithin/) and other conditions are actually executed on the foreign collection **"before"** the results are returned.

This is how [`$lookup`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/) deals with resulting joins that can possibly breach the 16MB limit. It's also the most efficient way you can presently "filter" results of the join.

So that's what you really want to do here instead.

---

Based on the data in your question, this statement:

```
db.members.aggregate([
  { "$lookup": {
    "localField": "_id",
    "from": "MobileUserLocations",
    "foreignField": "userId",
    "as": "userLocInfo"
  }},
  { "$unwind": "$userLocInfo" },
  { "$match": {
    "userLocInfo.location": {
      "$geoWithin": {
        "$centerSphere": [[76.9121, 10.2232], 5 / 3963.2]
      }
    }
  }}
])
```

Filters out the one location in `$lookup` that matches the constraint:

```
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("591553ffa4233a181506880c"),
    "userName" : "Test user",
    "userLocInfo" : {
        "_id" : ObjectId("59c3c37359f55d64d6e30297"),
        "userId" : ObjectId("591553ffa4233a181506880c"),
        "location" : {
            "type" : "Point",
            "coordinates" : [ 
                76.9121, 
                10.2232
            ]
        },
        "updatedOn" : ISODate("2017-05-12T07:12:48.626Z"),
        "status" : 1.0
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks man for the reply. But I am getting the fowllowing error:
"arguments to $lookup must be strings, unwinding: { preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: false } is type object".

Comment: @SanjayKumarNS You are misunderstanding the context of the answer. The pipeline you execute is the **first** block of code in the answer. The "second" area is the "explain output' demonstrating how "MongoDB parses the pipeline" when issued to the server. You don't actually use that second block.

Comment: Yes I have tried the first as well. But it not getting the records.

Comment: @SanjayKumarNS Remove some of the conditions then, and actually check that there is data that really does meet the `$geoWithin` constraint, or any other conditions in the statement. The "error" you told me about indicated that you were attempting to type in the contents of the explain output directly. You cannot **directly** use the `unwinding` or `matching` arguments. You specify these as `$unwind` and `$match` following `$lookup` and the server translates this.

Comment: I have given the matching arguments and I am getting the output without geowithin condition. And also have documents with those locations to get geowithin

Comment: @SanjayKumarNS Added a valid query and result to the end so you can see it yourself. The pipeline shown is correct. Your own query argument though need to be corrected. I'm showing you how to properly construct the pipeline.\